# How to manage SQL Server 2012 data backup company wise in one database

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I wrote a software which is company/corporate web based software. In one software, multiple companies can use one platform and one database. On login screen, software will filter according to company data and it will run at multiple locations. It works fine

The question is how to manage their company data in database/backups

1. How to manage data backup company wise (one database table has data from multiple companies)
2. How to restore their data according to company in one DB (other company data also exist in rest restore table).
3. It may primary key based or open id based DB table?

Is this possible to make a backup query with conditional data like company wise backup.

I searched but couldn't find any solid solution

Comment: SQL Server backups are **always** on the **database-level** - you cannot backup only parts from individual tables of a database. You will need to write your own "data extraction" logic that can pull out all the data for a given company, store it into a custom file and somehow "restore" that file into another database. There's no "built-in" solution for this in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks
Is this possible to make html table data to sql query file?

Comment: Video link of software
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z7vivUW1Xqy90WY1ybcuWohO8WQtJBf1/view